# c-w suddenly not working to switch panes

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

sorry, I don’t know if this is a problem at the VIM level, terminal emulator or with KDE.

I'm running vim-gtk3 in Debian Netrunner 20.01 which is KDE, and normally using Konsole, but also Terminator in debugging this, on a Thinkpad T410. I posted over at Netrunner forums, but no interest there.

I’ve been doing the following frequently for the last few months:

In Konsole, I go into VIM (usually through VIFM, but that doesn't seem to matter) and start editing a document. Then I do :new to get another panel, and then :Explore and start editing a second document, switching back and forth between the documents by using c-w (Ctrl-w) twice. Last night, something happened, and now when I press c-w, the first press makes the mouse pointer visible, and the second press makes the vim cursor blink once, but it does not switch panes.

The first time this happened, I did :new, then :Explore, then navigated up, and did /gyatso (a file name) and then I mistyped maybe hitting Ctrl I think, because vim came up with a small panel near the bottom with an error maybe about jump buffer being empty - something being empty anyway. I don’t know whether this typo caused all this, but since this time, I can no longer switch between panels.

Ctrl-W does exist as a KDE shortcut to close applications, but this has not changed. It’s always like that and doesn't normally interfere.

Things I’ve tried:

- Installed Terminator and tried in that, with the same problem, so it’s not just in Konsole
- Renamed the ~/.vim/vimrc
- Purged and reinstalled vim and everything starting with vim-
- Rebooted Netrunner
- Booted into BunsenLabs (another Debian) and in Terminator, using the same ~/.vim/vimrc from Netrunner KDE, it works fine in BunsenLabs.
- showkey gives 29 for Ctrl and 17 for u, which I suppose is correct.

I don’t recall that I did any upgrades in Synaptic, but maybe I did.

Any help or suggestions how to further troubleshoot this, or just a workaround are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 11/2/2020**

I created a new user on Netrunner, and vim is working fine there. But can anyone suggest how to know whether the problem is a vim config issue, or something from the OS intercepting the Ctrl-w before vim gets it?

**Edit 11/3/2020**

Someone told me how to clear up some of the KDE/Konsole stuff. I renamed `~/.config/konsolerc` and also `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` and logged out and back in, but this did not help. It seems like it must be something in vim.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You can try `vim --clean` to skip loading your vimrc or plug-ins, this could indicate whether it's something related to your config...

Comment: Also consider asking on [unix.se], this looks more related to KDE than to Vim itself...

Comment: Thank you. `vim --clean` did not help, but I appreciate knowing about it. Will try over on Unix & Linux as well.

Comment: Is there another way to change panes without using Ctrl-w ? Any reasonable workaround?

Comment: You can use the `winc` command (see `:h winc`), which allows you to change panes.

Comment: @Zorzi Thank you. I am/was very happy to have your work around. But then this happened (I hate this sort of solution, but it is fully solved.) In vim, I did `:map <C-E> :winc<Space>` to shorten the number of keystrokes. That worked fine, but now `<C-W>` has started working again, so it is fully functional normal vim in both Konsole and Terminator. I restored all the old config files, and it still works fine. So, I still have no idea what the actual problem was. Perhaps there’s some vim config I don’t know about. ~/.vim/vimrc is unchanged in six months. Make your comment an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @kr37 Nice to hear the problem's solved!

Comment: A mapping such as `noremap <C-E> <C-W>` would have worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `winc` command as follows:

```
:winc <KEY>
```

The `<KEY>` should be replaced by the key you'd be hitting after the usual `<C-w>`.

From the doc:

```
:[count]winc[md] {arg}
        Like executing CTRL-W [count] {arg}.  Example:
            :wincmd j
```